# Oracle PL/SQL utl_url.escape clob

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a large BLOB object which I need to convert to CLOB in base64 with encoded characters, I have tried to use **utl_encode.base64_encode** but it does not escape special characters like ={}+@~ etc. does anyone know how to escape those special characters with utl_url.escape? my code that I have:

```
  PROCEDURE base64encode ( i_blob in blob, io_clob in out nocopy clob) IS
    l_step                          pls_integer := 22500; 
    l_converted                     VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_buffer_size_approx            pls_integer := 1048576;
    l_buffer                        CLOB;
  BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_buffer, TRUE, dbms_lob.call);
    FOR i IN 0 .. trunc((dbms_lob.getlength(i_blob) - 1 )/l_step)
    LOOP
        l_converted := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(dbms_lob.substr(i_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1)));
        dbms_lob.writeappend(l_buffer, length(l_converted), l_converted);
        IF dbms_lob.getlength(l_buffer) >= l_buffer_size_approx THEN
            dbms_lob.append(io_clob, l_buffer);
            dbms_lob.trim(l_buffer, 0);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_lob.append(io_clob, l_buffer);
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(l_buffer);
  END base64encode;
```

and if I try to convert BLOB to base64 it gives me output like: 
**8J5G7Ty8t3Pn7T+9ce/+w/c//nn/Jd1VDTKhadyLoNKDDx/Cl+4/SHN7jFjSVFrj** <- not full base64 just single line,

But I need the output like this, with escaped characters:

**8J5G7Ty8t3Pn7T%2B9ce%2F%2Bw%2Fc%2F%2Fnn%2FJd1VDTKhadyLoNKDDx%2FCl%2B4%2FSHN7jFjSVFrj**

the result is large CLOB text, it does not fit in varchar2 variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have came up with a working solution, this code decodes base64 clob and escapes reserved chars. It is a bit slow, but it does the work. first, you need to call **base64encode** function from my main question, then pass the clob to this function. I hope it will help others too.

```
  FUNCTION encode64_clob(in_clob CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
    temp_chunk VARCHAR(4000);
    l_enter    NUMBER := 1;
    l_old_ent  NUMBER := 1;
    l_ent_cnt  NUMBER := 1;
    l_out      CLOB;
  BEGIN

    LOOP
      l_enter := instr(in_clob, chr(10), 1, l_ent_cnt);

      IF l_enter = 0 THEN
        temp_chunk := regexp_replace(substr(in_clob, l_old_ent, length(in_clob)), '[[:space:]]+', '');
        l_out      := l_out || temp_chunk;
        EXIT;
      END IF;

      temp_chunk := regexp_replace(substr(in_clob, l_old_ent, l_enter - l_old_ent), '[[:space:]]+', '');

      temp_chunk := utl_url.escape(url => temp_chunk, escape_reserved_chars => TRUE, url_charset => 'UTF-8');

      l_out := l_out || temp_chunk;

      l_ent_cnt := l_ent_cnt + 1;
      l_old_ent := l_enter;

    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_out;
  END;
```

Answer (score -1):

`APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE` might do the trick.

```
SELECT APEX_UTIL.URL_ENCODE('8J5G7Ty8t3Pn7T+9ce/+w/c//nn/Jd1VDTKhadyLoNKDDx/Cl+4/SHN7jFjSVFrj') 
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
8J5G7Ty8t3Pn7T%2B9ce%2F%2Bw%2Fc%2F%2Fnn%2FJd1VDTKhadyLoNKDDx%2FCl%2B4%2FSHN7jFjSVFrj
```

Comment: we do not have apex in our enviroment